# Is there any way to call function automatically from spring boot, at given date time fetched from PostgreSQL DB table?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa

Using spring boot, JPA, angular, PostgreSQL

Want to run the process automatically at particular date and time fetch from DB, and update status in DB accordingly

Purpose : We are giving 15 days free registration, let say user registered at 13th Dec., 13:05 then server should stop all the process of that user from 27th Dec., 13:05.

How can I call my function from spring boot automatically at 27th Dec., 13:05 (Available in PostgreSQL DB table)

I have tried scheduler with @Scheduled annotation also, but it runs after given interval of time.

Please suggest or hint any way to achieve this functionality.

Comment: The usual approach is to have a row with a timeout and then check periodically for rows with a timeout before `now()`, process, and delete them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three options:

- Configure Spring Scheduling.
- Use Polling.
- Build your own Scheduler (which I wouldn't).

## Configure Spring Scheduling

You might implement a `SchedulingConfigurer` and use the provided `ScheduledTaskRegistrar` accordingly.

You should be able to add new cron tasks with [`addCronTask`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/config/ScheduledTaskRegistrar.html) or probably refresh all with setCronTask.

I haven't tried it myself though ;-)

## Use Polling

If that doesn't work you might fall back to polling with a `select min(next_job_date) from jobs;` to find the next job and start it when its ready.

Comment: Thanks to guide, can you confirm what I get from SchedulingConfigurer and ScheduledTaskRegistrar that, I have to run the scheduler with @Scheduled at let say each mid night and get all times from DB for next day upto next mid night and register in ScheduledTaskRegistrar to run at specified time

Comment: Using ScheduledTaskRegistrar with addTriggerTask method, I can handle any db task and It does not require cron any more. I got help from very nicely explained blog at http://mbcoder.com/dynamic-task-scheduling-with-spring/